# Retrieve input file path on Shiny R Application

Tags: r, file, shiny

I have a Shiny Application in which the user browse for a file. Once the file is selected, I want it to be read into a table. The file is xlsx format, and it has two sheets, so I am using the function `readWorksheetFromFile(file path, sheet = 1)` to read in this table. In Shiny when you input a file, the line of code:

`input$file$datapath` gives you the path of a temporary location for that file. For some reason, this path is not valid in the `readWorksheetFromFile` function. Is there a way to get the exact file path of a file the user selects in R?

Answer (score 0):

The `input$file$datapath` provide a path to the temporary filename without the `.xlsx` extension. I think that could be the reason. You can rename it and try again.